# Iteratively slice list until end

Tags: python, range, iteration, slice

I am trying to process only k (10) portions of a list of lists at a time. The problem is that there are remainders (quotient) from dividing by 10 so I want to also process the remaining. Is there an elegant solution to this?

so far here is my code:

```
for x10 in np.arange(0, len(candidates), 10):
    indexed = enumerate([list(enumerate(entry)) for entry in candidates[[x10-10:x10]]])
```

Not a duplicate: I dont want to split the list into evenly sized chunks but into multiples of 10

Update: turns out x10:x10+10 did it... thought that would give me out of index error, strange

Comment: This looks like python code. You should tag it as such.

Comment: Wouldn't slicing `[x10:x10+10]` solve this?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes it worked! but why doesn't that give me an out of index error?

Comment: Slicing doesn't care about the actual length of the list.  `[1, 2][100:200]` is a perfectly valid (albeit empty) slice of the list `[1, 2]`